# I am trying to replicate this carousel of images and i am having issues with the styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to replicate the carousel with this code, but the buttons are not behaving how the image looks and I'm not very certain of the code, because it needs to be responsive and work on different screens.

CSS

```
.slider {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
}

.slide {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
}

.carouselInput1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 67px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #313133;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carouselInput2 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 19px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Arial";
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="carousel">
      <div class="slider">
        <button class= "next button">&#8249; </button>
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture1.jpg"/>
          <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
          <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture2.jpg"/>
        <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
        <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture3.jpg"/>
        <div class="carouselInput">
          <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
          <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture4.jpg"/>
        <div class="carouselInput">
          <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
          <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Be more specific with your question. You're not clear about your issue.

Comment: my code doesn't replicate the image exactly and I am asking if anyone can help with refining the code so it would look the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For carousel you must set max width and height for carousel in his shildren.

You can check my demo, where I realized carousel via your html/css with vanila JS: https://codepen.io/GTech1256/pen/GRKaNLY

**For the future**

- Set `alt` `width` `height` attribute on every `<img>`
- Use flex instead of inline-block if you can
- tag `p (.carouselInput1)` inherits `font` by default, so u can set `font` only on `body`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="carousel">
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture1.jpg" alt="picture description" width="300" height="100"/>
        <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
        <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture2.jpg" alt="picture description" width="300" height="100"/>
        <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
        <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture3.jpg" alt="picture description" width="300" height="100"/>
        <div class="carouselInput">
          <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
          <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img class="slide" src="../assets/Picture4.jpg" alt="picture description" width="300" height="100"/>
        <div class="carouselInput">
          <p class="carouselInput1">Lorem Ipsum dolore test content goes here and here if there is </p>
          <p class="carouselInput2">Name here, Location here</p>
        </div>
       <button class="prev button" disabled>&#8249;</button>
      <button class="next button">&#8815;</button>
    </div>

      <script>
        var btnNext = document.querySelector('.next.button');
        var prevNext = document.querySelector('.prev.button');
        var firstSlider = document.querySelector('.slider:first-child');

        var OFFSET_STEP_PX = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(firstSlider).width, 10);
        var OFFSET_MIN = 0;
        var OFFSET_MAX = (document.querySelectorAll('.slider').length - 1) * OFFSET_STEP_PX;
        var current_offset_px = 0;

        function setOffset(toUp) {
          console.log(OFFSET_MAX)
          toUp ? 
            current_offset_px += OFFSET_STEP_PX : 
            current_offset_px -= OFFSET_STEP_PX;

          validateOffset() // does not go beyond

          firstSlider.style.marginLeft = '-' + current_offset_px + 'px';
        }

        function validateOffset() {
          btnNext.disabled = false
          prevNext.disabled = false

          if (current_offset_px > OFFSET_MAX) {
            current_offset_px = OFFSET_MAX
            btnNext.disabled = true
          } else if (current_offset_px < OFFSET_MIN) {
            current_offset_px = OFFSET_MIN
            prevNext.disabled = true
          }
        }

        btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
          setOffset(true)
        })
        prevNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
          setOffset(false)
        })
      </script>
    <style>
    #carousel {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1000px;
      max-height: 300px; /* like height of .slider */
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* set button on center */
    .button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .button.next {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
    }

    .slider {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;

      transition: margin 0.3s;
    }



    .slider {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    .slide {
      width: 300px;
      height: 130px;
    }

    .carouselInput1 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 67px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #313133;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .carouselInput2 {
      width: 260px;
      height: 19px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #000000;
      font-family: "Arial";
    }
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, your code is crisp and thank for the advice I will google more about flex